# Schwarz Christoffel in two special cases

Tags: complex-analysis

The answer is given in [my book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=EjT3fE2SgGwC&pg=PA252), my question how one gets to this answer .This is the case of 1. two semi-infinite parallel cuts , and 2.Channel with right bend .At least in the first case I can see what dw/dz is working backwards , but I do not want to write down something that I do not understand....I have inserted an image here that hopefully people can see.....

[image: conformal maps]

Comment: You should have mentioned that your "book" is Schaum's Outline on Complex Variables to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A-11.**
Let $S^{-}$ be the lower part of the domain in Fig.8-35, that is, $$
S^{-}=\{w\mid \Im w<0\}\setminus \{w\mid w=u-\pi i, u\le -1\}.$$
First we find a mapping function $$w=F(z): \text{the upper half plane} \to S^{-}.$$ $S^{-}$ is an infinite open triangle. So we can apply Schwarz-Christoffel formula to $S^{-}$ as noted in p.247. 
$S^{-}$ has three vertices $w=\infty,$ $ -\infty$ and $-1-\pi i.$ We choose $z=-\infty,$ $0$ and $1$ which correspond to $w=\infty, -\infty$ and $-1-\pi i$ respectively.
 Note that by this choice of vertices $F((-\infty,0))=(-\infty,\infty)$.
By the Schwarz-Christoffel formula the mapping function 
$w=F(z)$ will be $$
F(z)=-1-\pi i+K\int_1^z \frac{\zeta -1}{\zeta }d\zeta .$$
Easy calculations shows that
$$
F(z)=-1-\pi i+K(z-1-\log z).
$$
We determine $K$ so that $F(x)$ $(x<0)$ is real. Thus $K$ should be $K=-1$ and we have $$
F(z)=-\pi i+\log z-z.$$
Secondly consider $w=F(z^2)$.  Since $z^2$ maps the first quadrant onto the upper half plane, $w=F(z^2)$ maps the first quadrant onto $S^{-}$.
Note that $\{z: z=it,t>0\}$ is  mapped onto $\{w: -\infty<w<\infty\}$. So we can use Schwarz's reflection principle to conclude that $w=F(z^2)=-\pi i+2\log z-z^2$ is a solution for **A-11**.

**A-12**.
The channel domain has four vertices $w=-p+i$, $-i\infty$, $0$  and $\infty.$ As mentioned in p.247, we can choose $3$ of prevertices arbitrarily, so we may assume$$
w=-p+i\longleftrightarrow z=\infty,\quad w=-i\infty\longleftrightarrow z=-1,\quad w=0 \longleftrightarrow z=0.$$ Let the remaining prevertex be $z=a\longleftrightarrow w=\infty$ (the value of $a$ is unknown at the present time).
Then the mapping function has the form
$$
F(z) = K\int_{0}^z (\zeta+1)^{-1}\zeta^{1/2}(\zeta-a)^{-1} \ d\zeta 
$$
by the Schwarz-Christoffel formula.
We have to determine the value of $a$ so that $F(\infty)=-p+i.$
\begin{align}
F(z)&=\frac{K}{a+1} \int_0^z \left( \frac{\sqrt{\zeta }}{\zeta -a}-\frac{\sqrt{\zeta }}{\zeta +1}\right) d\zeta, \\
\int_0^z  \frac{\sqrt{\zeta }}{\zeta +1} d\zeta &=\int_0^{\sqrt{z}}\frac{u}{u^2+1}\cdot 2udu=2\sqrt{z}-2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{z},     \\
\int_0^z \frac{\sqrt{\zeta }}{\zeta -a} d\zeta &=\int_0^{\sqrt{z}}\frac{u}{u^2-a}\cdot 2udu=2\sqrt{z}-2a\int_0^{\sqrt{z}}\frac{du}{a-u^2}\\
&=2\sqrt{z}-\sqrt{a}\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{z/a}}{1-\sqrt{z/a}}\right).
\end{align}

Therefore $$
F(z)=\frac{K}{a+1}\left(-\sqrt{a}\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{z/a}}{1-\sqrt{z/a}} \right)  +2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{z}\right).\tag{1}
$$
Since $$F(\infty)=\frac{K}{a+1}\left(-\sqrt{a}\log(-1)  +\pi\right)=-\frac{\pi\sqrt{a} K}{a+1}\left( -\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}+i\right),
$$

we choose $a$ and $K$ so that $$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}=p,\quad -\frac{\pi\sqrt{a} K}{a+1}=1.$$
Thus from $(1)$ we have $$
F(z)=\frac{2}{\pi}\left\{ \tanh^{-1}(p\sqrt{z})-p\tan^{-1}\sqrt{z}\right\}.
$$